# Include OR Group With Exposed Filters in View

Tags: 7, views

I have a view where I need to include an OR group for example (a + b) OR (C) as well as using Exposed Filters that will apply to both groups, giving something like (Ex1 + Ex2 + ((a + b) or c))). Is there any way I can make the exposed filters apply to both groups at the same time?

I thought it may be possible using nested or sub groups but I know it is not possible to create nested or sub groups in filters through the UI.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve it by adding new filter group from views UI.

[image]

**Edit:**
If your case is more special then you can achieve it using `hook_views_query_alter`.

```
if (!$new_feed) { 
  $query->where[0]['conditions'][1]['field'] = 'node.nid'; 
  $query->where[0]['conditions'][1]['value'] = array(); 
  $query->where[0]['conditions'][1]['operator'] = 'IN (' 3, 4 5')'; 
} 
else { 
  $query->where[2]['conditions'][1]['field'] = 'node.nid'; 
  $query->where[2]['conditions'][1]['value'] = array(); 
  $query->where[2]['conditions'][1]['operator'] = 'IN (1, 2, 3); 
}
```

You can unset where condition as per your use case.

Comment: thanks for your answer Yogesh, but as well as using the or group I need to use exposed filters which would apply to both filter groups, and this is the part I am having difficulty with. Perhaps I did not make it clear enough in my question but what I actually need is something like (Ex1 & Ex2 & ((A & B) or C)))

Comment: In this case you can also alter your views queries in and inside alter function you can create condition like you want. hook_views_query_alter

Comment: Thank you for that. Would you have an example at all I could look at?

Comment: Implement the hook and look into $query object. There you can find operator table column name and value.
if (!$new_feed) {
        $query->where[0]['conditions'][1]['field'] = 'node.nid';
        $query->where[0]['conditions'][1]['value'] = array();
        $query->where[0]['conditions'][1]['operator'] = 'IN (' 3, 4 5')';
      }
      else {
        $query->where[2]['conditions'][1]['field'] = 'node.nid';
        $query->where[2]['conditions'][1]['value'] = array();
        $query->where[2]['conditions'][1]['operator'] = 'IN (1, 2, 3);
      }
You can also unset where condition

Comment: Thank you very much. Perhpas if you can edit your answer to say that it can be done using hook_views_query_alter, I can then mark it as correct. Thanks again.